# Get subnet mask from GetAdapterAddresses()

Tags: c++, c, winapi, iphelper

I'm using the `GetAdapterAddresses()` method to get the ip addresses of all interfaces on the system.

I need to find the broadcast address of each interface. I can calculate this using the IP address and the subnet mask but I can't see the subnet mask in the IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES structure.

Is there any way to retrieve the subnet mask using `GetAdapterAddresses()`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`GetAdapterAddresses()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915.aspx) provides subnet masks only on Vista and later.

When looping through the unicast addresses pointed to by the `FirstUnicastAddress` field of the [`IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366058.aspx) record, the [`IP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366066.aspx) record includes an `OnLinkPrefixLength` field.  This field is not available on pre-Vista systems.  This field is the length of the subnet mask, in bits.  For IPv4 unicast addresses, you can use [`ConvertLengthToIpv4Mask()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb408402.aspx) to convert the `OnLinkPrefixLength` value into a subnet mask, which you can then use to mask the unicast IPv4 address as needed.

On pre-Vista systems, use [`GetIpAddrTable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365949.aspx) to get a list of the available IPv4 interfaces.  The [`MIB_IPADDRROW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366845.aspx) record contains a `dwAddr` field for the IPv4 address, a `dwMask` field for the subnet mask, and a `dwBCastAddr` field for the broadcast address.  You can loop through that table looking for each unicast IPv4 address reported by `GetAdapterAddresses()`, and then you will have their associated subnet masks and broadcast IP addresses.

Comment: Is there a way to convert the ULONG returned by `ConvertLengthToIpv4Mask()` to a string representation (Like "255.255.255.0")?

Comment: Ok I can use an in_addr structure and inet_ntoa. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer btw!  Just want to add that the MSDN documentation for IP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS is wrong for Windows Embedded Compact 7.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee494101(v=winembedded.70).aspx
It doesn't list OnLinkPrefixLength, but looking at the .h files, it is there.  I have confirmed that it is there.  (Same for newer versions).  It does not exist in CE 6 or lower (properly documented).